# Comparing approaches to managing free and bound variables.

Tags: logic, reference-request, notation, soft-question, first-order-logic

Corrections:

I originally said $\varphi(x, w_1 \cdots w_n, a)$ was a closed well-formed formula. It is not. I meant to say that within $\varphi$ the only free variables come from $x, w_1 \cdots w_n, a$, i.e. $\text{FV}(\varphi) \subset \{x, w_1 \cdots w_n, a\}$.

---

Comparing approaches to managing free and bound variables.

What are the different approaches to managing free and bound variables in well-formed formulas? Are there any references that explicitly compare multiple ways of doing it and talk about their advantages and disadvantages?

---

For example, here is Z(F)(C)'s [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) as presented by Wikipedia but with all variables made lowercase and some minor notational changes.

$$ \forall w_1\cdots w_n \mathop. \forall a \mathop. \exists b \mathop. \forall x \mathop. (x \in b) \leftrightarrow (x \in a \land \varphi(x_1, w_1 \cdots w_n, a)) $$

Note that all the variable symbols are bound.

In the convention used in the article, $\varphi$ is a well-formed formula. $\varphi(x_1, w_1 \cdots w_n, a)$ is a well-formed formula and the fact that $b$ does not appear in $(x_1, w_1 \cdots w_n, a) $ is significant. The fact that $b$ does not occur means that $b$ does not occur free in $\varphi$. I'm not sure how to define $\varphi(\vec{v})$ for an arbitrary $\vec{v}$ in this notation ... I usually think of it as a way of *declaring dependencies* in some sense where the exact interpretation depends on the context.

I think there are *some technical advantages* when defining syntax to making bound and free variable symbols disjoint. I didn't make up the idea of separating free and bound variables, but I don't remember where I saw it.

Let a lowercase Latin letter be a bound variable symbol and an uppercase Latin letter be a free variable symbol. Let $\psi[M:=\chi]$ be a capture-avoiding substitution replacing $M$ with $\chi$ in the well-formed formula $\psi$.

Using this convention, the above formula can be written as follows.

$$ \exists b \mathop. \forall x \mathop. (x \in b) \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land \varphi[X:=x]) $$

In this case, $\varphi$ is an ordinary well-formed formula with no restrictions placed on it. $A$ might occur in $\varphi$ or might not. $X$ might occur in $\varphi$ or might not. By virtue of being *well-formed* $b$ cannot occur free in $\varphi$ since it is inherently a bound variable. It is a little weird, though, that the names of free variables in $\varphi$ are *not* irrelevant; $X$ and $A$ both have special meanings because of the exact phrasing of the axiom schema.

So, in this one particular case, using a distinct collection of symbols for free and bound variables seems to simplify part of my task in defining an axiom schema, but it may not be more convenient in general.

Comment: you might find [de Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) relevant! there might be literature comparing de Bruijn indices to other methods of binding, which could provide a jumping-off point.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to say that $\varphi$ is a *closed* formula? "Closed formula" usually means the same as "sentence": no free variables. But $x,w_1,\dots,w_n,a$ may all occur free in $\varphi$.

Comment: I meant to say that the arguments to $\varphi$ capture all the dependencies that $\varphi$ has (and so the absence of $b$ is meaningful). Closed is definitely not the right word, but I don’t know what is.

Comment: The notation $\varphi(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is usually used to indicate the free variables of the formula $\varphi$ are among $v_1,\dots,v_n$. That is, every free variable in $\varphi$ is one of the $v_i$, but not all of the $v_i$ need to occur free in $\varphi$. This is a very useful notation, because we can then write $\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for the operation of substituting $a_i$ for every free instance of $v_i$. And it makes it clear that $\varphi$ naturally defines a subset of $A^n$ / an $n$-ary relation on $A$, for any structure $A$.

Comment: There is usually no need to similarly indicate the bound variables in a formula $\varphi$, because once bound, their identities are irrelevant. That is, you can trade out a bound variable (in its quantifier and in every instance within the scope of that quantifier) for a different variable without changing the meaning of the formula.

Comment: Thank you. The thing I always found confusing about $\varphi(\vec{v})$ is that it was used both to say $\text{FV}(\varphi) \subset \vec{v}$ *and* to say $\varphi[x_1 := \vec{v}_1 \cdots x_n := \vec{v}_n]$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th free variable ... so I always wondered whether the "name" of the parameter or its position in the argument list was more important. // De Bruijn indices are another good alternative. I've seen them before in discussions of lambda calculus, substitution is nontrivial though and requires you to add.

Comment: There is the approach used by Gentzen (the father of ND and Sequent Calc) to separate variables: $x,y$ used **only** bound, from *parameters*: $a,b$ used only free. Example with $\forall$-Intro rule: $\dfrac {\varphi} {\forall x \varphi [x/a]}$

Comment: I think some related (but not comprehensive) reading might be strewn across the Metamath Proof Explorer documentation, e.g. [ZFC Axioms Without Distinct Variable Conditions](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmzfcnd.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I think there are some technical advantages when defining syntax to making bound and free variable symbols disjoint. I didn't make up the idea of separating free and bound variables, but I don't remember where I saw it." The device of using different letters for bound variables [i.e. variables which serve to bind quantifier prefixes to places in simple or complex predicates] and for free variables [expressions whose prime use is as parameters/dummy names/"arbitrary" names, however you prefer to put it] is there in Gentzen's original 1930s natural deduction investigations, and then again in Prawitz's 1965 classic book. It is taken up in some later influential logic textbooks, beginning with those by Lemmon and Thomason.

Depending exactly how you set things up, the device -- inter alia -- enables you avoid fussing about unintended capturing of variables. But perhaps the main positive reason for adopting the device is not technical but [in a broad sense] philosophical or conceptual: it cleaves to the very good Fregean principle of perspicuously marking in *syntax*  important differences of *semantic* role.